# Anti-virus live CD

Tags: ubuntu, anti-virus, ntfs, livecd

I'm looking for a Linux Live CD/USB, that comes pre-configured with basic troubleshooting software, which I could use to check Windows computers.
My wish list:

- Anti-virus **(MUST HAVE)**
- Any software that can help fix a **NTFS** disk/partition

  - Defragmenter
  - Disk partitioner
  - Disk checker
  - Windows Registry editor (does that even exist in Linux?)
- Preferably Ubuntu/Debian based
- Preferably a light windows manager, like **XFCE** or **LXDE**

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the problem with a Linux Live CD is that fact that it does **not** fully support NTFS. You can use a Linux based anti-virus scanner but it won't be able to remove the problem because writing to an NTFS disk is not reliable.

Answer (score 4):

the **[Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)** is probably as close as it gets:

UBCD includes a variety of **Linux** boot disks (amongst them Trinux, based on ubuntu/debian), **Anti Virus** (F-Prot, McAfee, BugHunter), a gazillion of **Disk Tools**, the **Offline NT Password & Registry Editor**, and a lot more utilities ... no window manager though (text based menu).

you can easily create a bootable USB stick with UBCD, a script to do this automatically is included in UBCD

Comment: I have this one.  But it has so much stuff, and so user-unfriendly, that I'm affraid to use it.  JAJAJA.

Comment: user unfriendly? it's a text based user menu, what's user-unfriendly about using the up/down arrow and hit enter to select a category? or typing a number on the keyboard to start a program from a category? ^^

Comment: user-unfriendly because it has some much stuff, but not much explanation of how to use it.  Maybe if they concentrated on a couple of programs, per category, and had better documentation.  Just my opinion.

Comment: well, the aim is to provide a CD with utilities covering pretty much any aspect of computer repair and they're doing a pretty good job. if you prefer something more "point and click" style, then make yourself a BartPE Windows Live CD but you will have to add your tools manually, integrate plubins, you may have to make some of the programs 'portable' first, etc. but keep in mind that some of the tools you're looking for simply do not work in a win32 environment or their counterparts that do work, may require a commercial license (i.e. cost you money) while UBCD just works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately you can get most of that in the Linux-based [Avira AntiVir Rescue System](http://free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira_antivir_rescue_system.html). Mostly its file recovery and AV tools.

Comment: I just burned it.  I'll let you know how it went.  Thanks!

Comment: Tried it.  It froze while trying to mount the hard disk.  Too bad, I was hoping for it to work.  Maybe the problem was the machine itself.

Comment: Odd - I've used it on a number of computers in the past with no problems...

Comment: I'll keep it in my stash of tools, and try to use it again.  I have another PC waiting to be fixed.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its not a Linux disk, but you could always build a custom [BartPE disk](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/). It would give you a Windows-like environment with whatever tools you opted to build into it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a usb flash drive then you can use pendrive linux.  I've actually put together a pretty good how to right [here](http://howdoi-tech.blogspot.com).  If you are looking for a bootable cd that is great for cleaning windows software then I suggest [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)

Comment: Hiren's Boot CD is full of pirated software. It is illegal to use.

Comment: Didn't know that... sorry... however if you are talking about the Windows GUI, most IT people have XP licenses coming out of their noses...